# How-to leverage WordPress for creating Extended Social Profiles

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, buddypress, facebook, profiling

My question is actually quite simple, but I think there are a number of answers to choose from:

**If one were to use WordPress, what would be the most elegant way of creating a part of the website that has "People Profiles", whereby; they can update their own mini-blog, add images, assign them a multitude of taxonomies, etc. (basically having a very light version of Facebook functionality plus some e-commerce products specific to the person). Scalability would obviously be key too, would need to work for 10, 100, 1000+ profiles.**

I think my first instinct would be to try and go with BuddyPress as a support application from which these profiles would originate, but there are possibly other solutions?

What do you think?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that with:

- a regular instal of WordPress but
  with a lot of work and hacking around
  to get it where you want.
- a multisite install of WordPress that
  would make it a bit easier but still
  a lot of work and customization.
- a fairly easy case with BuddyPress.

  Basically it just installing BuddyPress ,some plugins and configuring it a bit not only the profiles but also the mini-blogs,multitude of taxonomies,images and e-commerce products specific to the person. its just for that.

So I'd say your best of with BuddyPress, and why not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try BuddyPress. BuddyPress allows extended profiles, plus your members can write their own blogs.